# How to manually log errors/crashes to appcenter in react native application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, exception, appcenter

I am creating an application with the use of react native and I want to handle exceptions in some cases when an application can get crashed. I want to show that exception in appcenter and also not want that the application actually crash. I am using appcenter already and implemented it for building the app. I am also getting crash reports there but it shows when the actual application got crashed. But I want only the reports there while not crashing the application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `appcenter-analytics` and `appcenter-crashes`

If you use the library, you can find out when a crash occurs.

- appcenter

[image]

To manage the event separately, the following method can be used.

- Example

```js
import Analytics from "appcenter-analytics";
...
Analytics.trackEvent("eventName", {
               [key]: value,
            });
```

- appcenter

[image]

Comment: Can it be used with an emulator also?

Comment: @MayankBalar Yes, of course